# Вывод счетчика цикла ASP MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Хочется отображать а странице, счетчик итераций цикла. Не знаю как это сделать.

Есть контроллер итогом работы, которого является обработанный эксель-файл. Вот собственно сам контроллер.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult GetBooks(HttpPostedFileBase uploadfile)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (uploadfile != null && uploadfile.ContentLength > 0)
            {

                Stream stream = uploadfile.InputStream;
                IExcelDataReader reader = null;
                if (uploadfile.FileName.EndsWith(".xls"))
                {
                    reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(stream);
                }
                else if (uploadfile.FileName.EndsWith(".xlsx"))
                {
                    reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream);
                }
                else
                {

                    ModelState.AddModelError("File", "Не правильный формат файла");
                    return View();
                }

                reader.IsFirstRowAsColumnNames = true;

                DataSet result = reader.AsDataSet();
                reader.Close();
                result.Tables[0].Columns.Add("OzonPrice", typeof(string));
                result.Tables[0].Columns.Add("LabPrice", typeof(string));
                result.Tables[0].Columns.Add("LabPriceSale", typeof(string));
                result.Tables[0].Columns.Add("LabPricePercentSale", typeof(string));
                for (int i = 0; i < result.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    string cell_value = result.Tables[0].Rows[i][15].ToString();

                    if (cell_value != "" && cell_value != "ISBN / ISMN")
                    {

                        string price_ozon = GetPriceOzon(cell_value);
                        string price_lab = GetPriceLabirint(cell_value);
                        string price_sale_lab = GetPriceLabirintSale(cell_value);
                        string percent_sale_lab = LabPricePercentSale(cell_value);
                        DataRow row = result.Tables[0].Rows[i];
                        row["OzonPrice"] = price_ozon;
                        row["LabPrice"] = price_lab;
                        row["LabPriceSale"] = price_sale_lab;
                        row["LabPricePercentSale"] = percent_sale_lab;
                    }

                }

                byte[] bytes = null;
                bytes = CreateExcelFile.CreateExcelDocumentAsStream(result, "Result.xlsx", HttpContext.Response);
                return File(bytes
            , "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
            , "Книги -" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + ".xlsx");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("File", "Please upload your file");
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Во вью это выглядит так.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("GetBooks", "Tools", null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken();
    @Html.ValidationSummary();

    <label class="text-info">Загрузить Excel файл</label>
    <input type="file" class="form-control" name="uploadfile" id="uploadfile" />
    <input type="submit" value="Отправить" class="btn btn-default" id="SubmitBtn" />
    <div id="divCount"></div>

}
```

Хочется, через ajax выводить данные с цикла в контроллере в слой `<div id="divCount"></div>` как это сделать?

Comment: Вам нужно вывести все данные с цикла? Или только текущую строку, которая обрабатывается в цикле?

Comment: @wardef Мне нужен просто счетчик. Можно через Ajax

Comment: Счетчик - имеется ввиду, количество строк в вашем exel файле?

Comment: @wardef Хотя бы вывод количества итераций в цикле for, дальше то я разберусь

Comment: Ну как минимум есть 2 способа, если я не ошибаюсь. 1) Использовать ViewBag, например: `ViewBag.Count =  result.Tables[0].Rows.Count;` во View `<div id="divCount">@ViewBag.Count</div>`.
2) Через модель, например: в контроллере `int count = result.Tables[0].Rows.Count; 
return View(count);` во View `<div id="divCount">@Model</div>`. UPD: Забыл добавить, это сработает только после отработки контроллера, то-есть интерактивности нет, если не используете асинхронные запросы

Comment: @wardef Мне нужна интерактивность к сожалению, нужно отображать прогресс

Comment: Тогда вам нужно работать с частичными представлениями